# Electron pass BrowserWindow to external main function (not IPC)

Tags: node.js, electron

I understand and can implement both **IPC** and `.remote()` from **main** <--> **renderers**.
This question is about an external function still in the main thread and sharing the instantiated `BowerserWindow`.

For example, `main.js`:

```
... 
let mainWindow = null;
...
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false, 
    width: 1024, 
    height: 728
});
...
```

I'm trying to access `mainWindow` from `foo.js` and can't seem to get there.

Psuedocode:

```
export default () => {
    let win = mainWindow // from main.js;
    win.webContents.send('toast', 'woohoo'); // Arbitrary Render side listener
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, although it seems like additional overhead as a lookup:

On `main.js`

```
foo(mainWindow.id)
```

On `foo.js(id: number)`

```
const win = BrowserWindow.fromId(id);
win.webContents.send('toast', 'woohoo');
```

I welcome any more efficient method.